# Drupal View Deleted by mistake

Tags: files, views

So this is my problem. I deleted a view for my drupal 5 site and have no idea to recreate it. I've tried to recreated the view but it's not the same what so ever. The view I deleted was for a video page. It displayed videos, from third-party sites. The view displayed the title and a thumbnail of the the embedded video. The view that I recreated only displays the video link and not the thumbnail too. I've tried altering the fields to display the thumbnails. But with no luck. Any Ideas?

Comment: You dont have a backup of your site?

Comment: I have the site set up locally from a backed up version of the database. The connection seems to work but I can't login to the admin control panel or visit any pages besides the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to restore a deleted view. Check if you have an old database dump somewhere (a regular backup, or maybe you created one when you put your site live). Depending on your hosting setup, your webhost may also have created backups of your server.

If that all fails, I'm afraid you will need to rebuild your view manually. While you're at it, consider upgrading your site to Drupal 7. Newer versions of Views make it really easy to export your view to code, so you can store your view in a version control system and never lose it again.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. This is what I did: I set up a local version of the site with the database and files from the live site. The homepage works, but none of the links seem to be working. I think it has something do with clean-urls? Any idea.

Comment: Could be a clean urls problem, yes. Just try it out; if example.com/user doesn't work, but example.com/?q=user does, it's clean urls related.